# Unable to resolve module `react-native-gesture-handler`

Tags: react-native

unable to resolve "react-native-gesture-handler" from "node_modules/@react-navigation/native/src/Scrollables.js"

```
E:\>npm install react-native-gesture-handler --save
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/naver/hammer.js.git

npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-13T05_04_32_3
58Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found the solution of this problem ..
It's Just version Error

npm install react-native-gesture-handler@1.3.0

When I try this 
It's Working

Comment: This version is outdated

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario I think you haven't install the gesture handler package.

For more information on React Native Gesture Handler please visit [here](https://software-mansion.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/getting-started.html)

**SOLUTION**

Inside your project root folder run this code :

If you are using npm -   `npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler`

If you are using yarn - `yarn add react-native-gesture-handler`

Once you have installed above package run your project using `react-native run`

**If you still getting errors open cmd via administrator and run above code**

Answer (score 1):

### Cause

Some some reason, autolinking is not working and had to manually link packages in both IOS and android.

### Specs

```json
"react": "17.0.1",    
"react-native": "0.64.2",    
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
```

### Solution

put `import 'react-native-gesture-handler';` at the top of the `app.js` or `index.js`

#### Android

##### Step 1

`implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')` in `app/build.gradle` file inside `dependencies {}` block.

##### Step 2

in `MainActivity.java`

```
package com.myapp;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "myapp";
  }

  @Override
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
      @Override
      protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
        return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

##### Step 3

add `import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerPackage;`  in `MainApplication.java` also add `packages.add(new RNGestureHandlerPackage());` in `getPackages()` function like below

```
    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
      // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
      packages.add(new MapsPackage());
      packages.add(new VectorIconsPackage());
      packages.add(new RNGestureHandlerPackage());
      return packages;
    }
```

##### Step 4

add following in `settings.gradle` file

```
include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../../../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')
```

> Note: Make necessary adjustments for `../../../` in your case it can be `../` because I am using monorepo concept.

Answer (score 0):

delete node_modoules

run `npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler` (additional android setup here - https://software-mansion.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Bare React Native#**

```
yarn add react-native-gesture-handler
```

** Update your MainActivity.java file  **

```
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;
```